# What's the best way (in Fortran 90) to return an array (of unknown size) of strings?

Tags: string, parsing, fortran, character, fortran90

I want to write a function that parses a file and return an array of the "matching" lines. I don't care if it is a function or a subroutine, but I am unsure about how to do that.

Let's make this concrete with an example: suppose we want to return an array of all the lines in file `inputFile` that start with a certain character `startingCharacter` and return these lines in an array `matchingLines`. For convenience, let's also return the number of lines in this output array and call that number `matchingLineCount`. (We'll assume lines are less than 256 characters.) The subroutine code for that example should look something like the following:

```
subroutine parse_file( inputFile, startingCharacter, matchingLines, matchingLineCount )

implicit none

character(len=*), intent(in) :: inputFile
character, intent(in)        :: startingCharacter
character(len=256), dimension(*), intent(out) :: matchingLines
integer, intent(out)         :: matchingLineCount

! Open file

! While there are still lines to be read....

    ! Read in a line
    ! See if line(1) == startingCharacter
    ! If it does, add it to matchingLines

! Close file

end
```

I suspect the trick is how to return a variable-length array....

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, use an allocatable array.  My typical approach is to read the file until EOF to count the lines, then rewind the file.  Allocate the array and read the file again, into the array.  Try this and post code if you have a problem.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/19723316/3157076.

Comment: I'm using F90 because the rest of my code is written in F90. (This isn't a stand-alone task, which another language would be better suited for.)

Comment: I only mean to ask because F90 is a very restrictive condition which will be awkward if you need to implement a single-pass method (such as when you can't `rewind`): I'd likely forget to deallocate a local array in that case, as I haven't had to do that in nearly twenty years.

Comment: Most codes people think are Fortran 90 are at least Fortran 95, if there are no strict official coding standards requiring only 90, go for 95 or even further.

Comment: @M.S.B.: I ended up using your answer -- I found it simpler and more straightforward than the posted answer. (I liked that it had actual code, but I didn't like how much code it had.) If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Best" is a bit subjective and depends on things like Fortran processor, the nature of the input file and what you regard as important (e.g. speed or memory footprint), but as an  example...

```
PROGRAM ReadArrayOfUnknownSizeOfStrings
  IMPLICIT NONE
  ! Apparently we can assume this.
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: max_string_length = 256
  ! For testing.
  CHARACTER(*), PARAMETER :: filename  &
      = 'ReadArrayOfUnknownSizeOfStrings.txt'
  CALL main
CONTAINS
  SUBROUTINE main()
    ! Logical unit number.
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: unit = 10
    CHARACTER(max_string_length), POINTER :: an_array(:)
    INTEGER :: i
    !****
    ! Generate the file for testing.
    OPEN( UNIT=unit, FILE=filename, ACTION='WRITE',  &
        STATUS='REPLACE', POSITION='REWIND' )
    ! Write some test content.
    WRITE (unit, "(A)") 'Mary had a little lamb'
    WRITE (unit, "(A)") 'ARestricting yourself'
    WRITE (unit, "(A)") 'it''s fleece was white as snow'
    WRITE (unit, "(A)") 'Ato Fortran 90'
    WRITE (unit, "(A)") 'and every where that Mary went'
    WRITE (unit, "(A)") 'Ain this day and age is just silly'
    WRITE (unit, "(A)") 'the lamb was sure to go'
    WRITE (unit, "(A)") 'Agiven the improvements in the language'
    WRITE (unit, "(A)") 'Mary had a little lamb'
    WRITE (unit, "(A)") 'Aand the support offered by current compilers'
    WRITE (unit, "(A)") 'her father shot it dead'
    WRITE (unit, "(A)") 'AAt least use Fortran 95'
    WRITE (unit, "(A)") 'now mary takes that lamb to school'
    WRITE (unit, "(A)") 'Aplus the "Allocatable TR"'
    WRITE (unit, "(A)") 'between two chunks of bread'
    CLOSE(unit)
    ! Read back the test data.
    ! Open the file for reading.
    OPEN( UNIT=unit, FILE=filename, ACTION='READ',  &
        STATUS='OLD', POSITION='REWIND' )
    CALL read_the_array(unit, 'A', an_array)
    ! Close the file.
    CLOSE(unit)
    ! Print the results.
    DO i = 1, SIZE(an_array)
      PRINT "(A)", TRIM(an_array(i)(2:))
    END DO
    DEALLOCATE(an_array)
  END SUBROUTINE main

  SUBROUTINE read_the_array(unit, matching_char, an_array)
    ! Select a size appropriate for your data.
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: initial_array_size = 10
    ! Logical unit connected for formatted input.
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: unit
    ! Initial character of a record to match.
    CHARACTER, INTENT(IN) :: matching_char
    ! The array of matching lines.
    CHARACTER(max_string_length), POINTER :: an_array(:)
    ! A temporary for growing an_array.
    CHARACTER(max_string_length), POINTER :: tmp(:)
    INTEGER :: next_index     ! Next index to use in an_array.
    !****
    ALLOCATE(an_array(initial_array_size))
    next_index = 1
    DO
      READ (unit, "(A)", END=900) an_array(next_index)
      IF (an_array(next_index)(1:1) == matching_char) THEN
        next_index = next_index + 1
        IF (next_index > SIZE(an_array)) THEN
          tmp => an_array
          ALLOCATE(an_array(SIZE(tmp) * 2))
          an_array(:SIZE(tmp)) = tmp
          DEALLOCATE(tmp)
        END IF
      END IF
    END DO
    900 CONTINUE      ! Here on end of file.
    ! Cut result back to size.
    tmp => an_array
    ALLOCATE(an_array(next_index-1))
    an_array = tmp(:SIZE(an_array))
    DEALLOCATE(tmp)
  END SUBROUTINE read_the_array
END PROGRAM ReadArrayOfUnknownSizeOfStrings
```

If you run the example code you might get a subliminal message...

Comment: It looks like that'll do it. I like that it scales by factors of two, and I appreciate that you posted actual code.